# How to identify 'mat-calendar-body-cell' in selenium java?

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

Basically the UI code is written in Angular and I am automating using selenium java. I am facing difficulties in identifying the elements of a calendar. Below is the sample code. Plz let me know how to access the dates.

[image]

Comment: Please give a screenshot of the UI of the calendar, and put HTML code in well formatted plain text, rather than screenshot. And what functionality you want do implement, like I want to input/read a date into/from calendar field

Comment: Please read why a [**`screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Try following CSS locator to identify a specific date using `aria-label` attribute:

```
By.cssSelector("td[aria-label='Jan 1, 2018']") // (or any date that you want to identify)
```

If you want `div` element of a specific date:

```
By.cssSelector("td[aria-label='Jan 1, 2018']>div") // (or any date that you want to identify)
```

You can parameterize the date value to make it more generic:

```
public void selectDate(String date)
    By.cssSelector("td[aria-label='" + date + "']") // using string concatenation. you can do Stirng.format method for better readability.
```